# Strange thing on onmouseover in my spinner animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I want to make a 360 degree 3D spinning list gallery. And I did it. Here is the demo: [my 3D spinner list jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/47u01npc/1/) (only keys ← & → works on jsfiddle). And here is the code (copy the entire code and try it in your browser :)

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        body {
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        ul#spinner { 
            transform-style: preserve-3d; 
            list-style-type: none;
            transform-origin: 50% 50% -500px; 
            transition: 1s;
            clear:both;
        }

        ul#spinner li { 
            width: 50%; 
            max-width: 380px;
            max-height: 380px;
            position: absolute;
            transform-origin: 50% 50% -500px;
            text-align: center;
            font-family: 'Optima', sans-serif;
            outline:1px solid transparent; 
        }

        ul#spinner li:nth-child(1) { transform: rotateY(0deg); }
        ul#spinner li:nth-child(2) { transform: rotateY(-45deg); }
        ul#spinner li:nth-child(3) { transform: rotateY(-90deg); }
        ul#spinner li:nth-child(4) { transform: rotateY(-135deg); }
        ul#spinner li:nth-child(5) { transform: rotateY(-180deg); }
        ul#spinner li:nth-child(6) { transform: rotateY(-225deg); }
        ul#spinner li:nth-child(7) { transform: rotateY(-270deg); }
        ul#spinner li:nth-child(8) { transform: rotateY(-315deg); }

        span:hover { 
            color: #c3c3c3; 
            cursor: pointer; 
            transform: scale(1.5);
            -moz-transform: scale(1.5);
            -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
        }
   </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="lower">
        <ul id="spinner">
            <li id="1" style="background-color:black;color:white" onmouseover="MouseOver.scaleup(this)" onmouseout="MouseOver.scaledown(this)">
                <h3>title1</h3>
                <p>paragraph1</p>
            </li>
            <li id="2" style="background-color:white" onmouseover="MouseOver.scaleup(this)" onmouseout="MouseOver.scaledown(this)">
                <h3>title2</h3>
                <p>paragraph2</p>
            </li>
            <li id="3" style="background-color:black;color:white" onmouseover="MouseOver.scaleup(this)" onmouseout="MouseOver.scaledown(this)">
                <h3>title3</h3>
                <p>paragraph3</p>
            </li>
            <li id="4" style="background-color:white" onmouseover="MouseOver.scaleup(this)" onmouseout="MouseOver.scaledown(this)">
                <h3>title4</h3>
                <p>paragraph4</p>
            </li>
            <li id="5" style="background-color:black;color:white" onmouseover="MouseOver.scaleup(this)" onmouseout="MouseOver.scaledown(this)">
                <h3>title5</h3>
                <p>paragraph5</p>
            </li>
            <li id="6" style="background-color:white" onmouseover="MouseOver.scaleup(this)" onmouseout="MouseOver.scaledown(this)">
                <h3>title6</h3>
                <p>paragraph6</p>
            </li>
            <li id="7" style="background-color:black;color:white" onmouseover="MouseOver.scaleup(this)" onmouseout="MouseOver.scaledown(this)">
                <h3>title7</h3>
                <p>paragraph7</p>
            </li>
            <li id="8" style="background-color:white" onmouseover="MouseOver.scaleup(this)" onmouseout="MouseOver.scaledown(this)">
                <h3>title8</h3>
                <p>paragraph8</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <span style="float:left;font-size:30pt" class="ss-icon" onclick="galleryspin('-')"><</span>
    <span style="float:right;font-size:30pt" class="ss-icon" onclick="galleryspin('')">></span>
</body>
<script>
    var angle = 0;
    function galleryspin(sign) { 
        var spinner = document.querySelector("#spinner");
        angle += !sign ? 45 : angle - 45; 
        spinner.setAttribute("style","-webkit-transform: rotateY("+ angle +"deg); -moz-transform: rotateY("+ angle +"deg); transform: rotateY("+ angle +"deg);");
    }

    /* cannot do it on hover in css, so I make it in javascript onmouseover */
    var MouseOver = {
        scaleup: function(source) {
            console.log("mouse in: " + source.id);
        },
        scaledown: function(source) {
            console.log("mouse out: " + source.id);
        }
    }

    document.body.onkeydown = function onKeyDown(event) {
        var PRESSED_KEY = event.keyCode;
        if(PRESSED_KEY == 37)
            galleryspin('-');
        else if(PRESSED_KEY == 39)
            galleryspin('');
    }
</script>
```

However, there are a couple of issues here that I cannot address.

First: There is a problem on onmouseover event for li 3 and li 7 on Chrome, that they do not work well with the event (only works when mouse over it for the first time), but the list work perfectly on other browsers. Can anyone helps me to figure out what cause the problem?

Second: What trick should I do here to keep the spinner always in the center horizontally like li 3 and li 7 do?

Really need your help, and I appreciated, also suggest anything for me to clarify the question more.